# Is there any way to access jekyll.environment value in javascript files?

Tags: jekyll

It is easy to check which JEKYLL_ENV is used in templates, but I didn't found a way to get its value in my *.js values, which I think should be very useful. 
Any ideas on how to achieve this without using inlined  tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't found a way to access this variable in JS files, so the best way to still use it was utilising window object.

So I am setting variable in my template with `<script>` tag like that:

```
{% if jekyll.environment == "test" %}
<script>
  window.testMode = true;
</script>
{% endif %}
```

and then later checking for `window.testMode` in JS.